# How to restrict user in domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I want restrict my users to make any file in any drive (also in his profile folder), user can only read data which has been upload in any drive by administrator, he should not be able to create file or modify it only he can view.

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Managing Permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770962.aspx) for details on how authorisation works in the file system.

Comment: will you please share how exactly we can implement.

Comment: If you use the link Managing Permissions you will see the Microsoft documentation for user permissions. Read that, and you will be able to implement your requirement.